# How to convert string dictionary value into dict type in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I am reading text from files and text looks like this:

```
"(id=336346860, name='Western Australia', slug='western-australia', has_public_page=True, lat=-26.0, lng=121.0)"
```

I would like to convert this to a dict. I tried to convert it into dict type but it's giving error:

```
fileOutput = "(id=336346860, name='Western Australia', slug='western-australia', has_public_page=True, lat=-26.0, lng=121.0)"
x = dict(fileOutput)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Can someone help to find out a solution for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237513/discussion-on-question-by-parth-savadiya-how-to-convert-string-dictionary-value).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something with [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse). Parse the string into the constructor of any function (doesn't have to be `dict`), then extract the keyword arguments. For example, start with

```
>>> mod = ast.parse('dict' + fileOutput)
>>> print(ast.dump(mod, indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Call(
                func=Name(id='dict', ctx=Load()),
                args=[],
                keywords=[
                    keyword(
                        arg='id',
                        value=Constant(value=336346860)),
                    keyword(
                        arg='name',
                        value=Constant(value='Western Australia')),
                    keyword(
                        arg='slug',
                        value=Constant(value='western-australia')),
                    keyword(
                        arg='has_public_page',
                        value=Constant(value=True)),
                    keyword(
                        arg='lat',
                        value=UnaryOp(
                            op=USub(),
                            operand=Constant(value=26.0))),
                    keyword(
                        arg='lng',
                        value=Constant(value=121.0))]))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

You can now extract the keywords pretty easily. You can expect arbitary trees even in the arguments, so you will have to apply [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to each keyword independently. This is not particularly difficult.

First sanitize the input a little to make sure it at least appears to be a call to the `dict` constructor (or whatever function name you prepended):

```
if len(mod.body) > 1 or not isinstance(call := mod.body[0].value, ast.Call) or call.func.id != 'dict':
    raise ValueError('Not just one dict')
if call.args:
    raise ValueError('Why are there positional args?')
```

Now you can extract the keywords:

```
>>> {x.arg: ast.literal_eval(x.value) for x in call.keywords}
{'id': 336346860,
 'name': 'Western Australia',
 'slug': 'western-australia',
 'has_public_page': True,
 'lat': -26.0,
 'lng': 121.0}
```

`ast.literal_eval` will crash if anyone tries to sneak in arbitrary function calls.

**TL;DR**

```
def parse_line(line):
    mod = ast.parse('dict' + fileOutput)
    if len(mod.body) > 1 or not isinstance(call := mod.body[0].value, ast.Call) or call.func.id != 'dict':
        raise ValueError('Not just one dict')
    if call.args:
        raise ValueError('Why are there positional args?')
    return {x.arg: ast.literal_eval(x.value) for x in call.keywords}
```

Comment: From one of the comments it becomes clear that OP try to parse [`instaloader.PostLocation` class](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.PostLocation) (even if they seem not to realise it) written as repr in the file. They should really find a way to make these files right.

Answer (score 2):

A more robust approach would be to prefix the string with an identifier, such as `_`, to make it a valid Python syntax for a function call, then use `ast.parse` to parse the string as Python code, traverse the code tree with `ast.walk`, and look for the `ast.Call` node, where there is the `keywords` attribute with a list of keyword arguments, from which you can extract the name from the `arg` attribute and the value from the `value` attribute. Since the `value` attribute itself can be an expression such as `-26.0` in your sample input, consisting of a constant of `26.0` and unary operation of `-`, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate the node to convert it to the value it represents:

```
{
    keyword.arg: ast.literal_eval(keyword.value)
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse('_' + fileOutput)) if isinstance(node, ast.Call)
    for keyword in node.keywords
}
```

With your sample input, this returns:

```
{'id': 336346860, 'name': 'Western Australia', 'slug': 'western-australia', 'has_public_page': True, 'lat': -26.0, 'lng': 121.0}
```

Comment: From one of the comments it becomes clear that OP try to parse [`instaloader.PostLocation` class](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.PostLocation) (even if they seem not to realise it) written as repr in the file. They should really find a way to make these files right.

Answer (score 1):

I built a custom class to fit into your requirements based on few assumptions listed below:

1. Input always starts and ends with parenthesis `()`.
2. Input may only include `""` (empty string) or `"()"` (empty parenthesis) or the actual values like `"(id=336346860, name='Western Australia', slug='western-australia', has_public_page=True, lat=-26.0, lng=121.0)"`.
3. Values will be only among python supported `str`, `bool`, `int`, `float`.
4. Key-value pairs are always seperated by `=`.
5. `,` (comma) is not a part of value. (ie. comma is not present anywhere in values

If any one of the above assumptions is broken, the class may not work as expected

---

Code is given below:

```py
from typing import Optional


class MyDict:
    def setRawElements(self):
        """Create a list by splitting the given string"""
        # Assumption #5
        # If there is any comma in the value, then the split may be inconsistent
        self.raw_elements = self.string.split(", ")

    def splitKeyValuePairs(self):
        """Split into key value pairs and create a internal dictionary"""
        for elem in self.raw_elements:
            # Assumption #4
            # If the key and the value is not seperated by '=', then the split may be inconsistent
            key, value = elem.split("=")
            self.dictionary[key] = value

    def setKeyTypes(self):
        """Type conversion"""
        for key, value in self.dictionary.items():
            # Assumption #3
            # Value must be one among (bool, str, float, int)
            if value in ["True", "False"]:
                # check if the value is a boolean [True, False]
                type_ = bool
            elif value and value[0] == value[-1] == "'":
                # check if the value is a str object
                self.dictionary[key] = self.dictionary[key][1:-1]
                # we need not convert a str to str, so we can skip the conversion part
                continue
            elif "." in value:
                # float values will have two parts, integer and fraction seperated by a period
                type_ = float
            else:
                # if above mentioned cases are not matched, ww assume that the type is int
                type_ = int
            # type conversion from str to excpected type
            self.dictionary[key] = type_(self.dictionary[key])

    def parse(self, string):
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.string = string
        if string and string[1:-1]:
            # Assumption #1 and #2
            # If string is not empty and not just empty parenthesis
            self.string = self.string[1:-1]  # remove parenthesis from start and end
            self.setRawElements()
            self.splitKeyValuePairs()
            self.setKeyTypes()
        return self.dictionary

    def __new__(cls, string: str) -> Optional[dict]:
        """Calling a class will return parsed dictionary"""
        return super().__new__(cls).parse(string)
```

To use the class, refer the below code:

```py
fileOutput = "(id=336346860, name='Western Australia', slug='western-australia', has_public_page=True, lat=-26.0, lng=121.0)"
x = MyDict(fileOutput)
print(x)
```

Below is the output:

```py
{'id': 336346860, 'name': 'Western Australia', 'slug': 'western-australia', 'has_public_page': True, 'lat': -26.0, 'lng': 121.0}
```

---

To check the types of the values, refer the below code:

```py
for key, value in x.items():
    print(key, value, type(value), sep=" - ")
```

Output:

```py
id - 336346860 - <class 'int'>
name - Western Australia - <class 'str'>
slug - western-australia - <class 'str'>
has_public_page - True - <class 'bool'> 
lat - -26.0 - <class 'float'>
lng - 121.0 - <class 'float'>
```

Comment: lol, I took 50 minutes to code this program. Please upvote for the valuable time spent  :)

Comment: The problem with writing your own parser for a complex language in under an hour is that there are bound to be plenty of gotchas that are unaccounted for. Besides the listed limitations such as the limited number of supported types and that strings may not contain commas, this would also fail if a string is quoted in double quotes or is a raw string or a docstring literal, or if a float does not contain a `.`, such as `1e99`.